In SAP ABAP Given an integer, write a program to output the number with the digits reversed
Given an integer, write a program to output the number with the digits reversed.
For example:

if the number entered is 23987446, the output should be 64478932.
if input 123456789 is given, the output should be 987654321.


You can find many answers in the Web (search "abap reverse string"), so what did you try, what is the issue?

How do I ask and answer homework questions?

Is that some kind of homework? :)
DATA number TYPE i VALUE 12345.
DATA(reversed_number) = reverse( CONV string( number ) ).
WRITE reversed_number.


You can ask it to ChatGTP. It will also give an explanation.
REPORT zreverse_digits.

DATA: lv_input  TYPE string,
      lv_output TYPE string,
      lv_char   TYPE c LENGTH 1.

PARAMETERS p_number TYPE i.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lv_input = p_number.
  DO strlen( lv_input ) TIMES.
    lv_char = lv_input+0(1).
    lv_output = lv_char && lv_output.
    SHIFT lv_input LEFT BY 1.
  ENDDO.

  WRITE: / 'Reversed number: ', lv_output.

